# Restoring from a old local copy of xampp folder where the project was stored

Tags: backup, xampp

Alright, I did a stupid mistake as my hard drive was failing. I only copied the whole xampp folder and now I want to restore the project. Is it possible and how can I do it. I know it's stupid and I'm only a begginer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reinstall xampp
2. Copy from your backup to your new xampp dir :

   - the www dir if your project(s) is/are in it
   - the app dir if your project(s) is/are in it
   - the alias of your project(s) (if any in the alias dir)

Your site is now working again, but your database is lost (so all posts, pages, options are lost too). To get them back, see if you have directory bin/mysql/mysql[version]/data/[your project] in your backup dir. If so you'll have to look in mysql doc to know how to reattach those database files to the new mysql.